# How does the CPU decode variable length instructions correctly?

Tags: assembly, x86, decode, instructions

On most architectures, instructions are all fixed-length.  This makes program loading and executing straightforward.  On x86/x64, instructions are variable length, so a disassembled program might look like this:

```
File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  00401000: 8B 04 24           mov         eax,dword ptr [esp]
  00401003: 83 C4 04           add         esp,4
  00401006: FF 64 24 FC        jmp         dword ptr [esp-4]
  0040100A: 55                 push        ebp
  0040100B: E8 F0 FF FF FF     call        00401000
  00401010: 50                 push        eax
  00401011: 68 00 30 40 00     push        403000h
  00401016: E8 0D 00 00 00     call        00401028
  0040101B: 83 C4 08           add         esp,8
  0040101E: 33 C0              xor         eax,eax
  00401020: 5D                 pop         ebp
  00401021: 83 C4 04           add         esp,4
  00401024: FF 64 24 FC        jmp         dword ptr [esp-4]
  00401028: FF 25 00 20 40 00  jmp         dword ptr ds:[00402000h]

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .text
```

It seems rather difficult to imagine how the CPU "knows" where one instruction ends and the next one begins.  For example, if I add the byte 0x90 (`NOP`) to the middle of the `XOR EAX,EAX` opcodes the program then disassembles as:

```
File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  00401000: 8B 04 24           mov         eax,dword ptr [esp]
  00401003: 83 C4 04           add         esp,4
  00401006: FF 64 24 FC        jmp         dword ptr [esp-4]
  0040100A: 55                 push        ebp
  0040100B: E8 F0 FF FF FF     call        00401000
  00401010: 50                 push        eax
  00401011: 68 00 30 40 00     push        403000h
  00401016: E8 0D 00 00 00     call        00401028
  0040101B: 83 C4 08           add         esp,8
  0040101E: 33 90 C0 5D 83 C4  xor         edx,dword ptr [eax+C4835DC0h]
  00401024: 04 FF              add         al,0FFh
  00401026: 64 24 FC           and         al,0FCh
  00401029: FF
  0040102A: 25
  0040102B: 00 20              add         byte ptr [eax],ah
  0040102D: 40                 inc         eax

  Summary

    1000 .data
    1000 .rdata
    1000 .reloc
    1000 .text
```

Which, predictably, crashes when run.

I'm curious exactly what the instruction decoder sees with that extra byte that makes it think the line `0040101E` is 6 bytes long, and the line originally at `00401028` is four seperate instructions.

Comment: The CPU does it precisely the same way your disassembler did it.

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking why with the extra byte they both completely screw up decoding the subsequent instructions

Comment: It's the same reason if you change "10 32 5" to "10132 5", the "10" and "32" get changed just by changing the space.

Comment: As for 0xFF/0x25, that's probably currently undefined. Up to that, there is no screw-up - what you see is what those bytes encode now. At run-time the CPU would trigger an invalid instruction fault ( assuming it hasn't already AV'd on the `xor`) and would never execute the `add/inc` pair.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When fetching an instruction, the CPU first analyses its first byte (the opcode). Sometimes it's sufficient to know the total length of the instruction. Sometimes it tells the CPU to analyse subsequent bytes to determine the length. But all in all, the encoding is not ambiguous.

Yes, the command stream gets screwed up if you insert random bytes in the middle willy-nilly. That's to be expected; not every byte sequence constitutes valid machine code.

Now, about your particular example. The original command was `XOR EAX, EAX` (33 C0). The encoding of XOR is one of those second byte dependent ones. The first byte - 33 - means XOR. The second byte is the ModR/M byte. It encodes the operands - whether it's a register pair, a register and a memory location, etc. The initial value C0 in 32-bit mode corresponds to operands EAX, EAX. The value 90 that you've inserted corresponds to operands EDX, [EAX+offset], and it means that the ModR/M byte is followed by 32 bits of offset. The next four bytes of the command stream are not interpreted as commands anymore - they're the offset in the mangled XOR command.

So by messing with the second byte, you've turned a 2-byte command into a 6-byte one.

Then the CPU (and the disassembler) resumes fetching after those four. It's in the middle of the `ADD ESP, 4` instruction, but the CPU has no way of knowing that. It starts with the 04 byte, the third one in the ADD encoding. The first few bytes at that point still make sense as commands, but since you've ended up in the middle, the original instruction sequence is utterly lost.

Comment: Fun fact: it's possible to craft obfuscated machine code that jumps back into the middle of an instruction that it previously ran.  Decoding from that point gives different instructions that don't repeat that jump.  This confuses many disassemblers, but the CPU just decodes instructions like always.  The key point is that a starting address is necessary for instruction decoding, because x86 instructions have no alignment requirements, and can be from 1 to 15 bytes long (including prefix bytes: the first byte doesn't even have to be an opcode).